# css clip-path overlap and border

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, clip-path

Here is a codepen of what I did:
https://codepen.io/dickeddocks/pen/opWBwQ

and this is what I am trying to achieve:
[a rough picture made in MS-Paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Err02.png)

so I am trying to make box 2, a div overlap box 1 which is also a div
and I want to make the yellow border cover the shape and not the container box. I did some research on stackoverflow and an answer to adding a border to a clip path shape was to add the the same clip path to the container.
But I am a little confused as the div itself is the container so why is the border not wrapping it.

html:

```
<div class="box-1">
BOX 1
</div>
<div class="box-2">
BOX 2
</div>
```

css:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: aqua;
}

.box-1 {
    padding: 25vh;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.box-2 {
    z-index: 200;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% -10%, 100% 11%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 11%);
    clip-path: polygon(50% -10%, 100% 11%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 11%);
    padding: 25vh;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    border-top: 10px solid yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go with clip-path for this, you have to first make the second box  overlap the first one by using  **negative margin** or change the top value. Then you have to create the small arrow using pseudo element (you can read more about [How do CSS triangles work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work))

So you will have something like this (without clip path):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.box-1 {
  padding: 25vh;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.box-2 {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -50px;
  padding: 25vh;
  background-color: #dede3b;
  border-top: 50px solid yellow;
}

.box-2:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #dede3b;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -50px;
  top: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-1">
  BOX 1
</div>
<div class="box-2">
  BOX 2
</div>
```

Then create the clip-path to hide the non needed part like this :

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.box-1 {
  padding: 25vh;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.box-2 {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -50px;
  padding: 25vh;
  background-color: #dede3b;
  border-top: 50px solid yellow;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 40px, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 40px, calc(50% + 50px) 40px, 50% 0, calc(50% - 50px) 40px);
  ;
}

.box-2:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #dede3b;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -50px;
  top: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-1">
  BOX 1
</div>
<div class="box-2">
  BOX 2
</div>
```

Here is an illustration to understand the polygon I used for clip-path:

[image]

---

Here is another solution without using clip-path (which will work better with all the browser). The idea is to use 2 pseudo element to create the double arrow:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.box-1 {
  padding: 25vh;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.box-2 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 25vh;
  background-color: #dede3b;
  border-top: 10px solid yellow;
}

.box-2:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 50px solid yellow;
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid transparent;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -60px;
  top: -55px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box-2:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #dede3b;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -50px;
  top: -40px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-1">
  BOX 1
</div>
<div class="box-2">
  BOX 2
</div>
```